# Can Nearest Neighbor Analysis help determine values for a Heat Map?

Tags: qgis, heat-map, nearest-neighbor

Given the below parameters (from Nearest Neighbor Analysis):

A) Is there a definite range my Radius value should be within?

B) Are there definite values my cell size should be near?

C) Is there a definite range my color map values should encompass or exclude?

What might the values be?

```
Observed mean distance:0.00550684136246
Expected mean distance:0.00927189095586
Nearest neighbor index:0.593928615929
N:185
Z-Score:-10.5662074435
```

Layer metadata:

```
X: 656 Y: 501 Bands: 1 
Origin: -75.2615,40.133
Pixel Size: 0.000475715,-0.000475715
No Data Value: -9999 
Data Type: GDT_Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point 
Pyramid overviews:
Layer Spatial Reference System: 
+proj=lcc +lat_1=40.96666666666667 +lat_2=39.93333333333333 +lat_0=39.33333333333334 +lon_0=-77.75 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=us-ft +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection): 
-75.2614514397764793,39.8947150902235208 : -74.9493824749561242,40.1330482478073591
```